# customize and android seekbar

Tags: android, customization, android-seekbar

I am trying to customize and android seekbar  use images  for background and progress.
but result is wrong，
[multiple background](https://iknow-pic.cdn.bcebos.com/f9198618367adab44fcad73d9bd4b31c8701e4b2)

resource image width=351px,height=110px,
[background](https://iknow-pic.cdn.bcebos.com/b21bb051f8198618355d23fa5aed2e738bd4e6b2),
[progress](https://iknow-pic.cdn.bcebos.com/b151f8198618367ade93b3a33e738bd4b31ce5b2)

android:progressDrawable="@drawable/drawable_clip_seek_bar" content

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item
        android:id="@android:id/background"
        android:width="351dp"
        android:height="110dp">
        <bitmap android:src="@mipmap/seek_bar_background" />
    </item>

    <item
        android:id="@android:id/progress"
        android:width="351dp"
        android:height="110dp">
        <clip>
            <bitmap android:src="@mipmap/seek_bar_progress" />
        </clip>
    </item>

</layer-list>
```

activity contentView

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/cardview_dark_background">

    <SeekBar
        android:layout_width="351dp"
        android:layout_height="110dp"
        android:background="@null"
        android:progressDrawable="@drawable/drawable_clip_seek_bar"
        android:thumb="@null"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: post some screenshots what does it look. for shure remove `android:width` and `android:height` from `<item` declarations inside `<layer-list` and your bitmaps should be inside `drawable` density buckets, not `mipmap`

Comment: remove android:width and android:height [image](https://iknow-pic.cdn.bcebos.com/3801213fb80e7bec2217cf9f3f2eb9389a506bfb),not background